# OOP organization with a Map

Tags: oop

I have a question about organizing code while also displaying fundamental OOP principles. My task is to implement a world (MxN grid) with robots who get instructions to move around in the form of strings. They are also given an initial starting position and orientation. Instructions are performed in completion one robot at a time.

I made two classes, Robot and Map, but when I completed my coding I realized that the Map did not really do anything, and when I want to test functions within the Robot class (making sure coordinates are within bounds, etc.) it seems that the Map class is more of a hassle than anything. However, I feel like it is important for demonstrating the separation of things. In this case is it necessary to have two classes?

Answer (score 1):

I think it does.

Map looks like a collection of Robots.  It's like an Eulerian control volume that Robots flux in and out of.  It keeps track of the space of acceptable locations in space and time.  It maintains rules (e.g. "only one Robot in a square at a time").  Feels analogous to a Board for Chess or Checkers game.

The problem appears to be that you can't figure out what the meaningful state and behavior of a Map is.

I can see how a Robot would interact with a Map: It would propose a motion, which is a vector with direction and magnitude, and interrogate the Map to see if it ran afoul of any of the rules of motion for a Robot.  Those are owned by the Map, not the Robot.  Different Maps might allow different rules of motion (e.g. no diagonal moves, one square at a time, etc.)

Comment: There are no movement restrictions besides moving out of the range of possible spaces. Wouldn't it just be better to throw an exception in that case?

Comment: i don't think so.  exceptions are a poor design for enforcing code control. anything goes?  what a crazy, pointless game.